# nginx folder redirect

Tags: nginx, rewrite, pcre

I'm trying redirect from an exact folder in nginx.conf

Given the URL:
domain.com/path1/path2/path3

Redirect to:
sub.domain.com/path1/path2/path3

Here's what I have so far:

```
location ~* ^/path1[\/?]$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*) http:sub.domain.com/$1 break;
}
```

I had it working with

```
location /path1 {
    rewrite ^/(.*) http:sub.domain.com/$1 break;
}
```

The problem with that is it also redirects a page like domain.com/path1moretext/someotherpath to sub.domain.com/path1moretext/someotherpath

Which is not what I want. (had to take out the "//" in the href code above because this is my first post, sorry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location / {

  rewrite ^\/path1\/(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 last;

  // rest of config for root

}
```

I'm from an Apache background and I've just started using Nginx in earnest, I've struggled with the re-writes myself, but, I've used the above recently without apparent issue.

Comment: Accomplishes the same thing, thanks.


Though I changed the rewrite to:


rewrite ^\/path1\/(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/path1/$1 break;


Not sure of the difference between last and break yet. Something to do with a limit of 10 options when using location? I'm just recalling other documentation from memory here.


Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
location = /path1 {
  rewrite ^ http://sub.domain.com$uri permanent;
}
location /path1/ {
  rewrite ^ http://sub.domain.com$uri?$args permanent;
}
```

edit: also [read this](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule#rewrite) for information on last/break/permanent/redirect.